# Can't pass video file from +page.svelte to +page.server.ts in a form

Tags: forms, file, video, server, sveltekit

I'm trying to move my submit video upload functionality from the client to the server. However, I'm struggling with passing the video file to the server in a form.

I'm using "svelte-file-dropzone" to retrieve the file, some processing is done and then I'm trying to submit the file through a hidden file input tag like this:

```html
<form  action="?/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" use:enhance={handleSubmit} id="upload" name="upload">
    <input hidden type="file" id="accepted-file" name="accepted-file" accept="video/*" bind:value={accepted}>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <button type="submit" class="button is-success is-fullwidth">Submit Video</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I console log the value "accepted" on the client side, everything is as it should be:

```js
{
    path: "test.mov"
    lastModified: 1640425487561
    lastModifiedDate: Sat Dec 25 2021 01:44:47 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard 
        Time) 
    name: "test.mov"
    size: 12458107
    type: "video/quicktime"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

...but when I try to access the file on the server:

```js
export const actions: Actions = {
    async upload({ request }) {
        const uploadFormData = await request.formData();

        const accepted = uploadFormData.get('accepted-file') as File;
        console.log("accepted file: ", accepted);

        return { accepted };
    }
}
```

...there's no file, i.e., "accepted" is blank.

I'm thinking that the problem *may* have something to do with how I'm attaching the file to the hidden input but am not too sure.

It's worth noting that my code works in all other circumstances, it only seems to fail in this instance. I've tried many workarounds but can't seem to be able to access the file no matter what I try.

I've been struggling with these new SvelteKit changes and also this is my first attempt at using TypeScript. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as I'm currently completely lost. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply set a file input `value` like this. To actually send your file, you have to modify the `files` list of the file input.

E.g.

```html
<input type="file" name="accepted-file"
    style:display="none"
    use:setFile />
```

```js
/** Svelte action to transfer the file to the input */
function setFile(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    const data = new DataTransfer();
    data.items.add(accepted); // Assuming that `accepted` is a File instance
    input.files = data.files;
}
```

(If the input always exists and is not only created once after the file has been processed, you can use [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-this) instead of an action to get a reference to the input and then update the `files` wherever you do the processing. You could also wrap the input in [`#key accepted`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-key) to force its recreation.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, H.B.! I was leaning towards that being the most likely source of my problems. I'll have to think about your response for a bit, as I'm just a hobby web developer. Though, I could see that you've put me on the right track. As it currently stands, it would appear that "accepted" is no longer a File instance by the time it makes it to the setFile function, as I'm getting a type error: "Failed to execute 'add' on 'DataTransferItemList': parameter 1 is not of type 'File'." I'll continue to try to digest your solution and see what I could come up with.

Comment: @jrfii: If you do not have a file instance, you may have to create a new one after you have done your processing. For that you can do something like `new File([blob], originalFile.name)` (with an optional third argument you can also specify a media type, if necessary; it can also be transferred from the original file's `type`, if the processing does not alter the type). ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File))

Comment: Thanks again for your follow-up, @H.B.! As it turns out, "accepted" is a File instance, I just had to wrap my input in an if-statement ({#if accepted != null}) to prevent setFile from running onMount. So, this is the correct answer, and I will mark it as so.

Comment: However, I'm still not out of the woods yet. As soon as made this correction, I received an error along the lines of "data.accepted returned from action cannot be serialized as JSON." I added "const acceptedFile = await accepted.text()" to my +page.server.ts file and then console.logged "acceptedFile," this overloaded my command line with some alien text that I assume was my video file being printed in characters. Now I'm a little worried about implementing my random attempts to get things working properly. Yet, I will persist, just a little more cautiously. :)

Comment: You cannot simply return the file as is. One common approach for transferring binary in JSON is to use something like hex or Base64 encoding (though this adds quite some overhead). Are you sure you even want to return the file again like this? I would expect videos commonly to be served as binary from a dedicated endpoint, so it can also be used e.g. as a `<video>` source.

Comment: You're correct, I don't want to return the file, I was just trying to understand how my data is being passed around. I removed the return statement and proceeded to upload my file to Vimeo (using "vimeo-upload"), setting "accepted" as my file, but now I'm getting the error "XMLHttpRequest is not defined." However, this code worked properly prior to moving it to the server and I know that vimeo-upload has set the XMLHttpRequest, as I've modified and patched the package. This is the last step for me in alpha phase, all of this headache to not transition to beta with an exposed access key.

Comment: After much thought, it finally dawned on me that I am going down an unnecessary rabbit hole here. I've decided that I just need to take two steps back in order to take the final step forward. I'm going to scrap my use of "vimeo-upload" and just go with the Vimeo API. Thank you so much for your assistance--people like you give me hope in the world! I'd probably still be beating my head against the wall if it wasn't for you. Plus, I learned something new in the process. All the best to you!